# SwingUtilities.invokeLater() displaying just during one frame

Tags: java, swing, swingutilities, invokelater

I'm using Swing in order to create a little java 2D game. I only try to display an image. Since i'm not on the EDT I'm using SwingUtilities.invokeLater() to do the stuff. When I use it, image is not displayed (in fact it's displayed during few miliseconds and disapear).
When I don't use SwingUtilities.invokeLater() the image is correctly displayed but I need to use invokeLater().

Here's my basic code :

```
public class Test {

/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                final BreizhFrame frame = new BreizhFrame();
                File imgFile = new File("src/test/lvl1-800x450.jpg");
                System.out.println(String.valueOf(imgFile.exists()));
                System.out.println(SwingUtilities.isEventDispatchThread());
                Image i;
                try {
                    i = ImageIO.read(imgFile);
                    frame.getGraphics().drawImage(i, 0, 0, null);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    } catch (InvocationTargetException | InterruptedException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

Any idea ?

Thanks.

Comment: `frame.getGraphics().drawImage(i, 0, 0, null);`  There is the problem..

Comment: Declare this "final BreizhFrame frame" outside main and try.

Comment: Take some time to read through [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not how you do it in Java. Yes, you are drawing the image, but after a while the control gets invalidated and it's re-drawn without your image.

[This tutorial should help you](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)